# C++ callback with lambda fails with bad_function_call

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, callback

I slightly modified the callback example found at [1] to move the registration in to the callee itself as follows.

```
// To build:
//   g++ -std=c++11 callback4.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Callback function.
typedef std::function<int(int)> CallbackFunction;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// "Caller" allows a callback to be connected.  It will call that callback.
class Caller
{
  public:
    // Clients can connect their callback with this.
    void connectCallback(CallbackFunction cb)
    {
      printf("setting the callback..\n");
      m_cb = cb;
      // This call works
      m_cb(10);
    }

    // Test the callback to make sure it works.
    void test()
    {
      printf("Caller::test() calling callback...\n");
      int i = m_cb(10);

      printf("Result (50): %d\n", i);
    }

private:
  // The callback provided by the client via connectCallback().
  CallbackFunction m_cb;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// "Callee" can provide a callback to Caller.
class Callee
{
  public:
    Callee(Caller c, int i) : m_i(i), caller(c) { }

    // The callback function that Caller will call.
    int callbackFunction(int i)
    {
      printf("  Callee::callbackFunction() inside callback\n");
      return m_i * i;
    }

    void registerCallback() {
      caller.connectCallback(
        [this](int i) { return this->callbackFunction(i); });
    }

private:
  // To prove "this" is indeed valid within callbackFunction().
  int m_i;
  Caller caller;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
  Caller caller;
  Callee callee(caller, 5);

  callee.registerCallback();

  // Test the callback. This fails.
  caller.test();

  return 0;
}
```

Here I capture the Callee by this reference in the lambda expression. But the call to test() to invoke within Caller failes throwing a bad_function_call at runtime. But calling the callback at registration time works. Any idea why that is? The output is given below.

> setting the callback..
>    Callee::callbackFunction() inside callback
>    Caller::test() calling callback...
>    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'
>    what():  bad_function_call

[1] http://tedfelix.com/software/c++-callbacks.html

Comment: You are modifying a copy of a copy of `caller`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take a look at the `Callee` constructor:

```
Callee(Caller c, int i) : m_i(i), caller(c) { }
```

Here you pass `Caller` *by value*, meaning you *copy* the object.

So in the `main` function the variable `caller` is *not* the same as `Callee::caller`. The `main` variable`caller` have not had any callback registered.

The easy solution is to use *references*:

```
class Callee
{
  public:
    Callee(Caller& c, int i) : m_i(i), caller(c) { }
    ...

  private:
    ...
    Caller& caller;
};
```

A better solution might be to rethink the design, and what problem you are actually trying to solve, and about the use-cases.

Comment: I see. That worked. But can I know why you think this could be better? Any issues that you see with this approach?

Comment: @chamibuddhika Passing around references mostly work, but it's not all situation where references can be used, making the whole scheme fall apart. It all depends very much on the use-cases though, and the problem you actually try to solve with this solution.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying.